# PHP DateInterval: Diff between same date in two different months is not one month

Tags: php, date

I am developing a subscription service where the user pays per month.

I am having two dates

1: 2012-12-05 ($today)

2: 2013-01-05 ($end_date)

For me, that is one month. But for PHP, that is only 30 days.

Here is some code (you can see the values of the dates mapped above)

```
$end_date_for_new_agents = clone $end_date;
$end_date_for_new_agents = $end_date_for_new_agents->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
$agent_period_months_obj = $today->diff($end_date_for_new_agents);
echo $agent_period_months_obj->format("%y-%m-%d")
```

This echos 0-0-30

Why is that and how can I make PHP calculate the difference between the same dates in different months as whole months?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should condider also the time, or the day can be not complete.

For example:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Rome");
$end='2013-01-05';
$intervalo = date_diff(date_create(), date_create($end));
echo $intervalo->format("Years:%Y,Months:%M,Days:%d,Hours:%H,Minutes:%i,Seconds:%s");
```

give as result:

```
Years:00,Months:00,Days:30,Hours:05,Minutes:59,Seconds:53
```

The following code

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Rome");
$start='2012-12-05';
$end='2013-01-05';
$intervalo = date_diff(date_create($start), date_create($end));
echo $intervalo->format("Years:%Y,Months:%M,Days:%d,Hours:%H,Minutes:%i,Seconds:%s");
```

give the result:

```
Years:00,Months:01,Days:0,Hours:00,Minutes:0,Seconds:0
```

Check if value of`$today` has also the time, if so you should extract only the date and forget the time